# How can I change the style properties of this element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a drop down menu for the mobile version of a website and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have the initial position where I want it (fixed in the upper right corner of the screen) but it does nothing when you click on the Menu tab.
Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sw358/)

```
<div id="mobile-nav-wrapper">
    <ul id="mobile-nav">
        <li>Main Menu</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Register</li>
            <li>FAQs</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
        </ul>
        <li>This Page</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Some Text</li>
            <li>Who?</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <span id="mobile-nav-button" onclick="pullmenu('#mobile-nav-wrapper')">Menu</span
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript function isn't a global.  You have configured JSFiddle to wrap it in an onload handler. It isn't accessible outside the scope of that function.

Don't use intrinsic event attributes, they depend on globals. [Bind your event handlers with JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead.

`span` isn't an interactive element. It doesn't appear in the focus order so has serious accessibility implications when you depend on people interacting with it. Use a button instead. Apply CSS if you don't like the way it looks.

```
<button type="button" id="mobile-nav-button">Menu</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('mobile-nav-button').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
   pullmenu('#mobile-nav-wrapper');
});

function pullmenu(etc) { etc }
</script>
```

Comment: You're right, a button is more logical than a span. However for some reason this piece of code isn't working. (and yes I replaced 'etc' with the appropriate code)

Comment: That's weird... it still isn't working here http://jsfiddle.net/qj26L/
Edit: I'm really hoping to get this working since it seems like the button has to be clicked once to activate, then clicked again to open.

Comment: You've reversed the order of the code I wrote and put the script before the HTML elements it is trying to modify. They don't exist when it runs.

Comment: Ah that makes sense then. Working now, but still has to be clicked twice in order to open the first time. Is there a way to open it on the first click? Only thing I can think of is changing it to a mouse down event

Comment: You're testing the **inline style**, but by default it doesn't have any. It is all coming from the cascade.

Comment: Alright, so I need to copy the initial style properties into the tags? Or is it possible to set them to the styles in the cascade via javascript?

Comment: Just test for the possibility that the value isn't set.

Comment: That piece of code works, but now it doesn't close at all haha. http://jsfiddle.net/up44g/

Comment: `x.top != "undefined"` - it will never be the string `"undefined"`, so that `if` will always be true.

Comment: woops got that fixed with "" now. Last thing I'm curious of is if there's a way to hide the box that appears around it when the button is clicked. This shouldn't be a big deal though since I don't believe mobile devices will get that box and it'll be hidden altogether on desktop view.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function pullmenu(menu) {
var x = document.getElementById(menu).style;
if (x.top == "-15em") {x.top="0";}
else {x.top="-15em";}
}
</script>
```

**HTML** :

```
<span id="mobile-nav-button" onclick="pullmenu('mobile-nav-wrapper')">Menu</span>
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sw358/2/)

Comment: Aha this works, thanks! If it was a longer piece of code, I would opt to keep the js in its own file, but this is short enough to copy/paste to each page.

Comment: Include it in each page, either via PHP include, or even Apache SSI includes, but copy/pasting into each static page will be a nightmare if you want to update this script down the line

Comment: I will change the span to a button as Quentin suggested, but at this point I am keeping the javascript code as is. eventListener isn't working.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, but due to Quentin's tolerance of my continuing problems/questions, I decided to go with his answer.